# import anaconda packages to IDLE?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib`, etc through Anaconda. I set my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include `C://Anaconda; C://Anaconda//Scripts; C://Anaconda//pkgs;`.

`import sys` `sys.path` shows that IDLE is searching in these Anaconda directories. `conda list` in the command prompt shows that all the desired packages are installed on Anaconda. But `import numpy` in IDLE gives me the error `No module named numpy`.

Suggestions? How do I tell IDLE where to look for modules/packages installed via Anaconda? I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't find an answer on any previous Overflow questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add those directories to `PATH`, not `PYTHONPATH`, and it should not include the `pkgs` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I like deets answer.
The simplest solution is to run IDLE from Anaconda.

If you are running MacOs (currently I am on Catalina - MacOs10.15) it is quite simple to run IDLE from Anaconda environment:

1. Launch Anaconda
2. Go to MacOs Terminal.
3. Type IDLE3

warning: if you type IDLE, the Python 2 IDLE will be opened ... but if you are using Python3 installed with Anaconda ... it doesn't work properly.

See also here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528112/17659912

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702361)

Answer (score -1):

You should try starting IDLE with the anaconda interpreter instead. AFAIK it's too primitive an IDE to be configurable which interpreter to use. So if anaconda doesn't ship one, use a different IDE instead, such as PyCharm, PyDev, Eric, Sublime2, Vim, Emacs.

Comment: FYI Anaconda comes with Spyder.