# ImportError: cannot import name _distributor_init aftar install anaconda

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, anaconda, installation

I installed the Anaconda package and checked the computer and I have the numpy's files but the computer cannot import the numpy package. I tried to run in the cmd: "pip install numpy" but the cmd could not run it

Comment: Please add more info to your question. Most importantly, how are you running Python? Are you sure the Conda environment is activate prior to launching Python?

Comment: Hey,
I run the python through the idell.
And I tried running short codes and importing other packages (for example xlrd) and with them no problem and the code did run.
The error only pops when trying to import numpy or pandas.

Comment: You mean **IDLE**? Make sure you are running the IDLE bundled with your Anaconda environment and not a default one in your system. Some of the comments on [this question about Anaconda and IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278398/idle-and-anaconda) may be helpful.

Comment: I sure I'm running the IDLE bundled with my Anaconda environment and not a default one in my system/ Do you have more ideas?

Comment: it would be preferable to edit your question to include the actual steps you took to verify this. That is, try creating a minimal reproducible example.  I would also have a look at `import sys; print(sys.path)` as this will reveal where the Python is searching for packages.